# Nestjs mongoose unit test: TypeError: <functionName> is not a function

Tags: unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

according to this [github repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/tree/main/apps/mongo-sample) we want to test a user sample
consider this test file :

```
const mockUser = (
  phone = '9189993388',
  password = 'jack1234',
  id = '3458',
): User => ({
  phone,
  password,
  _id: new Schema.Types.ObjectId(id),
});

const mockUserDoc = (mock?: Partial<User>): Partial<IUserDocument> => ({
  phone: mock?.phone || '9189993388',
  password: mock?.password || 'jack1234',
  _id: mock?._id || new Schema.Types.ObjectId('3458'),
});

const userArray = [
  mockUser(),
  mockUser('Jack', '9364445566', 'jack@gmail.com'),
];

const userDocArray = [
  mockUserDoc(),
  mockUserDoc({
    phone: '9364445566',
    password: 'jack1234',
    _id: new Schema.Types.ObjectId('342'),
  }),
  mockUserDoc({
    phone: '9364445567',
    password: 'mac$',
    _id: new Schema.Types.ObjectId('425'),
  }),
];

describe('UserRepository', () => {
  let repo: UserRepository;
  let model: Model<IUserDocument>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        UserRepository,
        {
          provide: getModelToken('User'),
          // notice that only the functions we call from the model are mocked
          useValue: {
            new: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser()),
            constructor: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser()),
            find: jest.fn(),
            findOne: jest.fn(),
            update: jest.fn(),
            create: jest.fn(),
            remove: jest.fn(),
            exec: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    repo = module.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
    model = module.get<Model<IUserDocument>>(getModelToken('User'));
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(repo).toBeDefined();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should return all users', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(model, 'find').mockReturnValue({
      exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(userDocArray),
    } as any);
    const users = await repo.findAll({});
    expect(users).toEqual(userArray);
  });

  it('should getOne by id', async () => {
    const userId = '324';
    jest.spyOn(model, 'findOne').mockReturnValueOnce(
      createMock<Query<IUserDocument, IUserDocument>>({
        exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(
          mockUserDoc({
            _id: new Schema.Types.ObjectId(userId),
          }),
        ),
      }) as any,
    );
    const findMockUser = mockUser('Tom', userId);
    const foundUser = await repo.findById(new Schema.Types.ObjectId(userId));
    expect(foundUser).toEqual(findMockUser);
  });
```

and this is the user document file:

```
export interface IUserDocument extends Document {
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  email?: string;
  password: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  nationalCode?: string;
  phone: string;
  address?: string;
  avatar?: string;
}
```

the 1th and 2nd test are passed but the third one throws:

`TypeError: this.userModel.findById is not a function`
also the interface is extended from mongoose Document, the `findById` function is not recognized in the test.

this is [the github repo](https://github.com/emirom/emart) available.
so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by the way, i needed the constructor to be called via `new` so i preferd to define a mock class like this:

```
class UserModelMock {
  constructor(private data) {}
  new = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(this.data);
  save = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(this.data);
  static find = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser());
  static create = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser());
  static remove = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(true);
  static exists = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(false);
  static findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser());
  static findByIdAndUpdate = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser());
  static findByIdAndDelete = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
  static exec = jest.fn();
  static deleteOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true);
  static findById = jest.fn().mockReturnThis();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice how in your `UserModel` mock you don't provide a mock function for `findById`

```js
{
  provide: getModelToken('User'),
  // notice that only the functions we call from the model are mocked
  useValue: {
    new: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser()),
    constructor: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockUser()),
    find: jest.fn(),
    findOne: jest.fn(),
    update: jest.fn(),
    create: jest.fn(),
    remove: jest.fn(),
    exec: jest.fn(),
    findById: jest.fn(), // <-------------- Add this
  },
},
```

There needs to be a `findById` method in that set of methods that you mock.

Comment: you are correct, `findById` was missed , also `findById: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()` should be added because of  chained call of `exec()` in the orginial method.